# How can I exploit the wordpress template hierarchy to render a different post template depending on category name/slug?

Tags: wordpress, hierarchy

Apologies if this appears simple to some, but I have scaled high and low and I'm not finding a solution here to my problem, which is:

I have a website set up with Wordpress in which posts can fall under one of three categories: reviews, views, news - the slugs associated with each of these category names are the same.

Currently, calling up the web page of any individual post classified under any of these categories will see it rendered by the file single.php.

However, I want to make a slight adaption to the rendering of the post when it falls within the 'reviews' category. I have copied and renamed the original single.php file to single-post-reviews.php (no custom posts here, I will just confirm and I would like, if possible, to avoid child-theming here - not good practice, I know), but I am not seeing the new rendering from my new file.

I've also tried renaming to single-reviews.php which hasn't worked either - so could someone tell me what exactly I'm missing here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress Template Hierarchy for [Single Posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post) doesn't factor in the current post category (likely due to the fact you can have multiple categories). Due to this, you have 2 viable options to your problem.

1) You can modify `single.php` to check for the post category, and if it's categorized under `reviews`, do something. This makes sense if you're just adding a small amount of markup in one or two places, or even hiding a few lines conditionally.

2) You can override the page template that's loaded based on the post's category using the [`single_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) filter. Because I don't know exactly *what* you're doing, I'm going to elaborate more on this method. Take the following function:

```
add_filter( 'single_template', 'so51913799_review_template' );
function so51913799_review_template( $single_template ){
    global $post;

    if( has_category( 'reviews' ) ){
        $single_template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-post-reviews.php';
    }

    return $single_template;
}
```

If you put it in your `functions.php` file, it will make use of the [`has_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_category/) function (I prefer this to [`in_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) since `in_category` just returns `has_category` anyways) and if it matches, it will update the `$single_template` variable to `single-post-reviews.php`. This assumes that the file is inside your `/wp-content/themes/ACTIVE-THEME/` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for this .... truly appreciated, I was tearing my hair out. I'll go with option number two here, I think, which seems to be the better approach for possible future category-based customisation for single posts for other categories. Thanks again ....